# Encode text from Tex file to UTF-8 format

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, latex

I have **.tex** file that can have universal encoding types from **Latin, Cp...., ISO-...., or UTF-..** or whatsoever. I need to encode this text file to parse the content and then store it to some kind of database type like SQLite and so on. Problem occur when I use java (only prog. language I can use) so if the **tex** contains for example japan symbols or any other, it parse this **variable char** wrong. Do you have advice how to encode the text to universal that I could right after that parse (my parser just extract content from commands and so on.)

```
\begin{japanese}
日本語は\textbf{難しい}！
\end{japanese}
```

But not only for Japanase encoding, but general. I know, that there exists MathJax but I need to parse the content and **store it first into database.**

Thank you

Comment: The file is what's encoded. What encoding is the file in? To read a file correctly, use `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FILE), ENCODING)` or something like that. **Do not** use `FileReader`.

Comment: Ok @KarolS, but what If Im using java and I don't know, how to get file encoding, cause there isn't any library, which will detect the encoding type of current file? For example, what If the file is encoded as Cp1250 and that file contains above mentioned japanase characters? What then? Because after reading char by char with the InputStreamReader, that characters will be presented as ,,?".